# Spinnaker keeps showing disabled stages in Jenkins pipeline UI

Tags: spinnaker

I have a pipeline with a few disabled stages:

```json
{
  "enabled": false,
  "completeOtherBranchesThenFail": true,
  "continuePipeline": false,
  "failPipeline": false,
  "parameters": {
    "FOO": "bar"
  },
  "type": "jenkins"
}
```

The doc states that disabled stages are hidden from the UI [1]:

> `enabled` - Determines if stage will be available in the UI.

However, those stages are still present in the UI.

When I go to `Configure Pipeline` > `Edit stage as JSON`, the `enabled` flag is set to `false`, so the UI has the right value.

1. https://spinnaker.io/guides/operator/custom-job-stages/#creating-a-custom-job-stage

Spinnaker version 1.23.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find how to *hide* a stage, however I found one can skip it using `stageEnabled` [1].

It takes a Spring Language Expression like so:

```json
{
  "stageEnabled": {
    "expression": "false", // you can also use SpEL, e.g. ${someBoolean}
    "type": "expression"
  },
  "completeOtherBranchesThenFail": true,
  "continuePipeline": false,
  "failPipeline": false,
  "parameters": {
    "FOO": "bar"
  },
  "type": "jenkins"
}
```

Or from the UI editor: `Execution Options` > `Conditional on Expression` > Enter `false` [2].

1. https://docs.armory.io/docs/spinnaker-user-guides/using-dinghy/#stage-fields
2. https://spinnaker.io/guides/user/pipeline/expressions/#dynamically-skip-a-stage